# plupload custom header and queue delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plupload

Using the plupload jquery upload form (www.plupload.com) I have two questions for those who are familiar with this package.

Most example plupload forms as in the supplied s3.php example in the downloaded zip work fine, but I am missing the following:

1. Custom header. How can I customize the header with the colored plus logo in the left and the text 'Select files \n Add files to the upload queue and click the start button.' to a custom header ?
2. Removing pending uploads from queue. In this example http://www.plupload.com/examples/queue I can select a file for upload and then in the far right of the entry with that file there appears a red [-] icon for deleting the item from the queue.
   How can I enable that in a plupload form ? The examples and documentation do not tell anything about this.

Thanks,

Klaas